# Org-mode checkbox, How do i extract the checked values?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I have the following org-checkbox.

```
Project 1
    [x] module 1
    [x] module 2
    [] module 3
    [x] module 4
```

How do i extract the checked values of `Project 1`
and pass the result to the code below?

```lisp
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp
    (json-pretty-print module-list)
#+END_SRC
```

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: What "code below"?  `json_print` is not known to my emacs (there is a `json-pretty-print` from `json.el` but no `json_print`) and the rest is eitherr pseudocode or a syntax error. Why don't you describe what output you expect and leave it at that? Also specify where the output is to go: in the Org mode buffer, some other buffer, to a file? While you are at it, you should also fix the Org mode file to make it legal,  Are you expecting the source block to be in the same file *always*, or are you interested in a more general function? If the latter, how is the input list specified?

Comment: You need to specify how the json output looks like; if you can't do that then you need to think more about your use case.  (Where are you going to copy paste the `json` code;  how does it look like; do they look like `import module` etc)  Think about it. The example I have added show that the org mode checklist are pretty compex (that is, they could be nested), so your assumption that it is a simple checklist is a bit of an approximation.  You need to think more about how the output looks like.  My guess is you don't need `json`;  are you importing in to `haskell` or `js` or `python`.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you aren't comfortable with `elisp`, but can work with `javascript`.

The snippet below gets you from `elisp` to `json`.

How you manipulate that resulting structure to a form that fits your needs, is left as an exercise to you.

---

1. Copy the following snippet to `todo.org`

```
* TODO Organize party [2/4]
  - [-] call people [1/3]
    - [ ] Peter
    - [X] Sarah
    - [ ] Sam
  - [X] order food
  - [ ] think about what music to play
  - [X] talk to the neighbors
```

2. Copy the following snippet to `*scratch*` and do `M-x eval-buffer`

```lisp
(defun simplify-org-data (tree)
  (cond
   ((stringp tree)
    (substring-no-properties tree))
   ((and (consp tree)
         (not (symbolp (car tree))))
    (mapcar #'simplify-org-data tree))
   ((and (consp tree)
         (symbolp (car tree)))
    (append
     (list (nth 0 tree)
           (cl-loop for (a b . rest) on (nth 1 tree) by #'cddr
                    if (or
                        (memq a '(:contents-begin
                                  :contents-end
                                  :parent
                                  :begin
                                  :end
                                  :pre-blank
                                  :post-blank
                                  :post-affiliated
                                  :structure
                                  ))
                        (null b))
                    do (ignore)
                    else
                    append (list a (simplify-org-data b))))
     (simplify-org-data (org-element-contents tree))))
   (t tree)))

(defun org-tree-to-json (&optional in-data)
  (interactive)
  (let* ((tree (or in-data (org-element-parse-buffer)))
         (json-file (format "%s.json" (file-name-sans-extension (buffer-file-name))))
         (simplified-data (simplify-org-data tree))
         (json-string (with-temp-buffer
                        (save-excursion
                          (insert (json-encode (simplify-org-data tree))))
                        (json-pretty-print-buffer)
                        (buffer-string))))
    (unless in-data
      (write-region json-string nil json-file nil nil nil t))
    json-string))
```

3. `C-x C-f todo.org`, and do `M-x org-tree-to-json`.
4. Above command would have written `todo.json`.
5. `C-x C-f todo.json`, and this what you will see

```json
[
  "org-data",
  null,
  [
    "headline",
    {
      "raw-value": "Organize party [2/4]",
      "level": 1,
      "todo-keyword": "TODO",
      "todo-type": "todo",
      "title": [
        "Organize party ",
        [
          "statistics-cookie",
          {
            "value": "[2/4]"
          }
        ]
      ]
    },
    [
      "section",
      null,
      [
        "plain-list",
        {
          "type": "unordered"
        },
        [
          "item",
          {
            "bullet": "- ",
            "checkbox": "trans"
          },
          [
            "paragraph",
            null,
            "call people ",
            [
              "statistics-cookie",
              {
                "value": "[1/3]"
              }
            ],
            "\n"
          ],
          [
            "plain-list",
            {
              "type": "unordered"
            },
            [
              "item",
              {
                "bullet": "- ",
                "checkbox": "off"
              },
              [
                "paragraph",
                null,
                "Peter\n"
              ]
            ],
            [
              "item",
              {
                "bullet": "- ",
                "checkbox": "on"
              },
              [
                "paragraph",
                null,
                "Sarah\n"
              ]
            ],
            [
              "item",
              {
                "bullet": "- ",
                "checkbox": "off"
              },
              [
                "paragraph",
                null,
                "Sam\n"
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ],
        [
          "item",
          {
            "bullet": "- ",
            "checkbox": "on"
          },
          [
            "paragraph",
            null,
            "order food\n"
          ]
        ],
        [
          "item",
          {
            "bullet": "- ",
            "checkbox": "off"
          },
          [
            "paragraph",
            null,
            "think about what music to play\n"
          ]
        ],
        [
          "item",
          {
            "bullet": "- ",
            "checkbox": "on"
          },
          [
            "paragraph",
            null,
            "talk to the neighbors\n"
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

FWIW,

1. `org-element-parse-buffer` on `todo.org` looks like this

```lisp
#2=(org-data
    nil
    #1=(headline
        (
         :raw-value "Organize party [2/4]"
         :begin 1
         :end 194
         :pre-blank 0
         :contents-begin 29
         :contents-end 189
         :level 1
         :priority nil
         :tags nil
         :todo-keyword
         #("TODO" 0 4
           (face
            (org-todo org-level-1)
            fontified t))

         :todo-type todo
         :post-blank 3
         :footnote-section-p nil
         :archivedp nil
         :commentedp nil
         :post-affiliated 1
         :title
         (#("Organize party " 0 15
            (
             :parent #1#))
          (statistics-cookie
           (
            :begin 23
            :end 28
            :value "[2/4]"
            :post-blank 0
            :parent #1#)))

         :parent #2#)
        #3=(section
            (
             :begin 29
             :end 194
             :contents-begin 29
             :contents-end 189
             :post-blank 3
             :post-affiliated 29
             :parent #1#)
            #5=(plain-list
                (
                 :type unordered
                 :begin 29
                 :end 189
                 :contents-begin 29
                 :contents-end 189
                 :structure #4=((29 2 "- " nil "[-]" nil 101)
                                (55 4 "- " nil "[ ]" nil 71)
                                (71 4 "- " nil "[X]" nil 87)
                                (87 4 "- " nil "[ ]" nil 101)
                                (101 2 "- " nil "[X]" nil 120)
                                (120 2 "- " nil "[ ]" nil 159)
                                (159 2 "- " nil "[X]" nil 189))

                 :post-blank 0
                 :post-affiliated 29
                 :parent #3#)
                #6=(item
                    (
                     :bullet "- "
                     :begin 29
                     :end 101
                     :contents-begin 37
                     :contents-end 101
                     :checkbox trans
                     :counter nil
                     :structure #4#
                     :pre-blank 0
                     :post-blank 0
                     :post-affiliated 29
                     :tag nil
                     :parent #5#)
                    #7=(paragraph
                        (
                         :begin 37
                         :end 55
                         :contents-begin 37
                         :contents-end 55
                         :post-blank 0
                         :post-affiliated 37
                         :parent #6#)
                        #("call people " 0 12
                          (
                           :parent #7#))
                        (statistics-cookie
                         (
                          :begin 49
                          :end 54
                          :value "[1/3]"
                          :post-blank 0
                          :parent #7#))
                        #("\n" 0 1
                          (
                           :parent #7#)))
                    #8=(plain-list
                        (
                         :type unordered
                         :begin 55
                         :end 101
                         :contents-begin 55
                         :contents-end 101
                         :structure #4#
                         :post-blank 0
                         :post-affiliated 55
                         :parent #6#)
                        #9=(item
                            (
                             :bullet "- "
                             :begin 55
                             :end 71
                             :contents-begin 65
                             :contents-end 71
                             :checkbox off
                             :counter nil
                             :structure #4#
                             :pre-blank 0
                             :post-blank 0
                             :post-affiliated 55
                             :tag nil
                             :parent #8#)
                            #10=(paragraph
                                 (
                                  :begin 65
                                  :end 71
                                  :contents-begin 65
                                  :contents-end 71
                                  :post-blank 0
                                  :post-affiliated 65
                                  :parent #9#)
                                 #("Peter\n" 0 6
                                   (
                                    :parent #10#))))
                        #11=(item
                             (
                              :bullet "- "
                              :begin 71
                              :end 87
                              :contents-begin 81
                              :contents-end 87
                              :checkbox on
                              :counter nil
                              :structure #4#
                              :pre-blank 0
                              :post-blank 0
                              :post-affiliated 71
                              :tag nil
                              :parent #8#)
                             #12=(paragraph
                                  (
                                   :begin 81
                                   :end 87
                                   :contents-begin 81
                                   :contents-end 87
                                   :post-blank 0
                                   :post-affiliated 81
                                   :parent #11#)
                                  #("Sarah\n" 0 6
                                    (
                                     :parent #12#))))
                        #13=(item
                             (
                              :bullet "- "
                              :begin 87
                              :end 101
                              :contents-begin 97
                              :contents-end 101
                              :checkbox off
                              :counter nil
                              :structure #4#
                              :pre-blank 0
                              :post-blank 0
                              :post-affiliated 87
                              :tag nil
                              :parent #8#)
                             #14=(paragraph
                                  (
                                   :begin 97
                                   :end 101
                                   :contents-begin 97
                                   :contents-end 101
                                   :post-blank 0
                                   :post-affiliated 97
                                   :parent #13#)
                                  #("Sam\n" 0 4
                                    (
                                     :parent #14#))))))
                #15=(item
                     (
                      :bullet "- "
                      :begin 101
                      :end 120
                      :contents-begin 109
                      :contents-end 120
                      :checkbox on
                      :counter nil
                      :structure #4#
                      :pre-blank 0
                      :post-blank 0
                      :post-affiliated 101
                      :tag nil
                      :parent #5#)
                     #16=(paragraph
                          (
                           :begin 109
                           :end 120
                           :contents-begin 109
                           :contents-end 120
                           :post-blank 0
                           :post-affiliated 109
                           :parent #15#)
                          #("order food\n" 0 11
                            (
                             :parent #16#))))
                #17=(item
                     (
                      :bullet "- "
                      :begin 120
                      :end 159
                      :contents-begin 128
                      :contents-end 159
                      :checkbox off
                      :counter nil
                      :structure #4#
                      :pre-blank 0
                      :post-blank 0
                      :post-affiliated 120
                      :tag nil
                      :parent #5#)
                     #18=(paragraph
                          (
                           :begin 128
                           :end 159
                           :contents-begin 128
                           :contents-end 159
                           :post-blank 0
                           :post-affiliated 128
                           :parent #17#)
                          #("think about what music to play\n" 0 31
                            (
                             :parent #18#))))
                #19=(item
                     (
                      :bullet "- "
                      :begin 159
                      :end 189
                      :contents-begin 167
                      :contents-end 189
                      :checkbox on
                      :counter nil
                      :structure #4#
                      :pre-blank 0
                      :post-blank 0
                      :post-affiliated 159
                      :tag nil
                      :parent #5#)
                     #20=(paragraph
                          (
                           :begin 167
                           :end 189
                           :contents-begin 167
                           :contents-end 189
                           :post-blank 0
                           :post-affiliated 167
                           :parent #19#)
                          #("talk to the neighbors\n" 0 22
                            (
                             :parent #20#))))))))
```

2. `(simplify-org-data (org-element-parse-buffer))` looks as below.  IOW, it essentially removes all the "crap" from `org-element-parse-buffer`.

```lisp
(org-data
 nil
 (headline
  (
   :raw-value "Organize party [2/4]"
   :level 1
   :todo-keyword "TODO"
   :todo-type todo
   :title
   ("Organize party "
    (statistics-cookie
     (
      :value "[2/4]"))))
  (section nil
           (plain-list
            (
             :type unordered)
            (item
             (
              :bullet "- "
              :checkbox trans)
             (paragraph nil "call people "
                        (statistics-cookie
                         (
                          :value "[1/3]"))
                        "\n")
             (plain-list
              (
               :type unordered)
              (item
               (
                :bullet "- "
                :checkbox off)
               (paragraph nil "Peter\n"))
              (item
               (
                :bullet "- "
                :checkbox on)
               (paragraph nil "Sarah\n"))
              (item
               (
                :bullet "- "
                :checkbox off)
               (paragraph nil "Sam\n"))))
            (item
             (
              :bullet "- "
              :checkbox on)
             (paragraph nil "order food\n"))
            (item
             (
              :bullet "- "
              :checkbox off)
             (paragraph nil "think about what music to play\n"))
            (item
             (
              :bullet "- "
              :checkbox on)
             (paragraph nil "talk to the neighbors\n"))))))
```

Comment: The first `tree` should be `in-data` in `org-tree-to-json`. The second `tree` should be `simplified-data` - maybe? Where does `-transform` come from? I guessed from `dash.el` but it doesn't seem to be defined there, at least in the version I have.

Comment: Thanks.  I was trying to use `-tree-map` or `-tree-map-nodes` and found it unsatisfactory.  That is where the back history of `-transform` .  `-transform` synonymous with `simplify-org-data`.  The `data` (or the parse tree) gets simplified in two senses (a) The buffer positions of parsing tokens are stripped; the properties that are null are stripped (b) The `:parent` property is removed.  (With the `:parent` property lurking around, the lisp structure will be cyclic, and you will run in to issues with `json-encode`.   Try again.  I will be happy to correct any further problems.

Comment: I have fixed the snippet now.  Try again.  If it works, says so.  The snippet I have shared goes miles beyond the scope of the original question (obviously), and the snippet could be useful for people who want to work with `js`-data (as opposed to `lisp` data).

Comment: To add to my earlier comment, one can flatten the `:parent` references to an "id" by using `org-export-get-reference`. In other words, there is no need to strip `:parent`; it can be replaced with org ids.  This way one get richer `json` data with `:parent` (but without the buffer positions). (The prefix `org-export`  in `org-export-get-reference`  is a hint that it is meant for use within an `export` context; IME, setting `info` to `nil` in `org-export-*` APIs usually "works")

Comment: I can run the snippet without errors now: thanks! One more nit: `simplified-data` is not used any longer, so you can get rid of one of the calls to `simplify-org-data` in `org-tree-to-json`.

Answer (score 1):

This response has to be read in conjuction with https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/73824/31220

1. Copy the below snippet to `todo.json`
2. Put your cursor on `#+begin_src emacs-lisp ...` and do `C-c C-c`.
3. Ensure that the resulting `json` `src_block` reflect the state of the checklist

```
** TODO Organize party [2/4]
:PROPERTIES:
:ID:       checklist
:END:
  - [-] call people [1/3]
    - [ ] Peter
    - [X] Sarah
    - [ ] Sam
  - [X] order food
  - [ ] think about what music to play
  - [X] talk to the neighbors


#+name: checklist-json
#+begin_src emacs-lisp  :result value verbatim :wrap src json
  (org-tree-to-json (org-element-map (org-element-parse-buffer) 'headline
              (lambda (headline)
            (when (string= (org-element-property :ID
                                 headline)
                       "checklist")
              headline))
              nil
              t))

#+end_src

#+RESULTS: checklist-json
#+begin_src json
[
  "org-data",
  null,
  [
    "headline",
    {
      "raw-value": "Organize party [2/4]",
      "level": 1,
      "todo-keyword": "TODO",
      "todo-type": "todo",
      "title": [
        "Organize party ",
        [
          "statistics-cookie",
          {
            "value": "[2/4]"
          }
        ]
      ]
    },
    [
      "section",
      null,
      [
        "plain-list",
        {
          "type": "unordered"
        },
        [
          "item",
          {
            "bullet": "- ",
            "checkbox": "trans"
          },
          [
            "paragraph",
            null,
            "call people ",
            [
              "statistics-cookie",
              {
                "value": "[1/3]"
              }
            ],
            "\n"
          ],
          [
            "plain-list",
            {
              "type": "unordered"
            },
            [
              "item",
              {
                "bullet": "- ",
                "checkbox": "off"
              },
              [
                "paragraph",
                null,
                "Peter\n"
              ]
            ],
            [
              "item",
              {
                "bullet": "- ",
                "checkbox": "on"
              },
              [
                "paragraph",
                null,
                "Sarah\n"
              ]
            ],
            [
              "item",
              {
                "bullet": "- ",
                "checkbox": "off"
              },
              [
                "paragraph",
                null,
                "Sam\n"
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ],
        [
          "item",
          {
            "bullet": "- ",
            "checkbox": "on"
          },
          [
            "paragraph",
            null,
            "order food\n"
          ]
        ],
        [
          "item",
          {
            "bullet": "- ",
            "checkbox": "off"
          },
          [
            "paragraph",
            null,
            "think about what music to play\n"
          ]
        ],
        [
          "item",
          {
            "bullet": "- ",
            "checkbox": "on"
          },
          [
            "paragraph",
            null,
            "talk to the neighbors\n"
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
#+begin_src json
[
  "org-data",
  null,
  [
    "headline",
    {
      "raw-value": "Organize party [2/4]",
      "level": 1,
      "todo-keyword": "TODO",
      "todo-type": "todo",
      "title": [
        "Organize party ",
        [
          "statistics-cookie",
          {
            "value": "[2/4]"
          }
        ]
      ]
    },
    [
      "section",
      null,
      [
        "plain-list",
        {
          "type": "unordered"
        },
        [
          "item",
          {
            "bullet": "- ",
            "checkbox": "trans"
          },
          [
            "paragraph",
            null,
            "call people ",
            [
              "statistics-cookie",
              {
                "value": "[1/3]"
              }
            ],
            "\n"
          ],
          [
            "plain-list",
            {
              "type": "unordered"
            },
            [
              "item",
              {
                "bullet": "- ",
                "checkbox": "off"
              },
              [
                "paragraph",
                null,
                "Peter\n"
              ]
            ],
            [
              "item",
              {
                "bullet": "- ",
                "checkbox": "on"
              },
              [
                "paragraph",
                null,
                "Sarah\n"
              ]
            ],
            [
              "item",
              {
                "bullet": "- ",
                "checkbox": "off"
              },
              [
                "paragraph",
                null,
                "Sam\n"
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ],
        [
          "item",
          {
            "bullet": "- ",
            "checkbox": "on"
          },
          [
            "paragraph",
            null,
            "order food\n"
          ]
        ],
        [
          "item",
          {
            "bullet": "- ",
            "checkbox": "off"
          },
          [
            "paragraph",
            null,
            "think about what music to play\n"
          ]
        ],
        [
          "item",
          {
            "bullet": "- ",
            "checkbox": "on"
          },
          [
            "paragraph",
            null,
            "talk to the neighbors\n"
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
#+end_src
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you new to `org-mode`?

```
Project 1
    [x] module 1
    [x] module 2
    [] module 3
    [x] module 4
```

**This is not at all a checklist ...**

You need to take sometime to read the manual, and the habit of reading the instructions manual--be it `emacs` or an an `ikea` item--is going to serve you for your lifetime.

That said I don't want you to feel discouraged, so read on ...

This is what you are trying to do, and having difficulty in articulating it. Put your cursor in the `babel` block, and do `C-c C-c`.  You will get a bunch of `import` statements which you insert via `noweb` reference at the top of the library you are trying to build.

```
#+name: module-list
- [X] module 1
- [X] module 2
- [] module 3
- [X] module 4

#+name: build-imports
#+begin_src emacs-lisp  :results value :wrap src js
  (let* ((data (org-element-parse-buffer))
         (plain-list
          (org-element-map
              data
              'plain-list
            (lambda (plain-list)
              (when (string= (org-element-property :name
                                                   plain-list)
                             "module-list")
                plain-list))
            nil
            t)))
    (apply #'concat
           (org-element-map
               plain-list
               'item
             (lambda (item)
               (when (memq (org-element-property :checkbox item) '(on))
                 (format "import \"%s\";\n"
                         (org-element-map item 'paragraph
                           (lambda (paragraph)
                             (let ((s (car (org-element-contents paragraph))))
                               (when s
                                 (replace-regexp-in-string "\n+" " " (substring-no-properties s) t t))))
                           nil
                           t))))
             nil nil t)))

#+end_src

#+RESULTS: build-imports
#+begin_src js
import "module 1 ";
import "module 2 ";
import "module 4 ";
#+end_src
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more general solution for getting checked box values from NAME.

```lisp
(defun get-checkbox (name)
  (let (items)
    (org-element-map
        (org-element-parse-buffer) 'plain-list
      (lambda (plain-list)
        (when (string= name (org-element-property :name plain-list))
          (dolist (i (org-element-property :structure plain-list))
            (let ((position (car i))
                  (value (nth 4 i)))
              (save-excursion
                (when (string= value "[X]")
                  (goto-char position)
                  (push (substring (string-trim (thing-at-point 'line t)) 6) items))))))))
    (nreverse items)))
```

```
#+name: module-list
- Project 1
  - [X] module 1
  - [X] module 2
  - [ ] module 3
  - [X] module 4

#+begin_src bash :results output :var modules=(get-checkbox "module-list")
echo Modules include:
echo "${modules[*]}"
#+end_src

#+results:
: Modules include:
: module 1 module 2 module 4
```